# download tweets of a specific language only

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am trying to download tweets done in a specific language without any search criteria. The API documentation is not very helpful in this regard. Has anyone else done this before? Can we do the same with Twitter Streaming API also?

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: sorry my bad... using tweepy, I am trying to make the following query work `api.geo_search(query='lang=ur',lat=73,long=33)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with the RestAPI query syntax (I primarily use the StreamingAPI) but I gave a quick glance over the API reference. Try using `lang=ur` instead of `'lang=ur'`. That is per the docs: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

A couple additional things, and I could be mistaken, but based on docs, it appears the query is initiated with `(q,_____)` as opposed to `(query=____)`. Second, I believe you need to add `geocode=`and a radius (in km/mi) to your lat/long search. So your query should be `geocode="73,33,1km"`

As far as the StreamingAPI, yes you can do the same. The parameter will be `language=_`. https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters, http://stats.seandolinar.com/collecting-twitter-data-using-a-python-stream-listener/

Answer (score 0):

With the help of GetOldTweets3 (https://pypi.org/project/GetOldTweets3/), you can download tweets by filtering over few criteria, as shown below:

```
tweetCriteria = got.manager.TweetCriteria().setQuerySearch('Coronavirus')\
                                       .setSince("2020-02-15")\
                                       .setUntil("2020-03-29")\
                                       .setMaxTweets(5)\
                                       .setNear('India')\
                                       .setLang('en')
tweets = got.manager.TweetManager.getTweets(tweetCriteria)
for tweet in tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
    print(tweet.date)
    print(tweet.geo)
    print(tweet.id)
    print(tweet.permalink)
    print(tweet.username)
    print(tweet.retweets)
    print(tweet.favorites)
    print(tweet.mentions)
    print(tweet.hashtags)
    print('*'*50)
```